# biblatex-chicago and mk4ht oolatex: formatting errors

Tags: biblatex, tex4ht, chicago-style

The MWE below using biblatex-chicago yields a few formatting errors  when formatted by `mk4ht oolatex` (the same file formatted by `pdflatex` produces correct output):

Report – with mk4ht oolatex: no space between title and number; month and day missing

Online – with mk4ht oolatex: underscores missing in URL; month and day missing; “Visited on” instead of “Accessed”

Article – with mk4ht oolatex: “number” instead of “no.”; month and day missing

Book – with mk4ht oolatex: “edition” instead of “ed.”; “volumes” instead of “vols.”

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{test1.bib}
@online{online,
    Author = {Online, Otto},
    Date = {1999-11-30},
    Title = {A Website},
    Url = {http://www.xxx.zzz/path_with_underscores/},
    Urldate = {2011-07-28}}
@report{report,
    Author = {Report, Rob},
    Date = {1999-10-29},
    Institution = {University of Massachusetts},
    Number = {99-02},
    Title = {A Stochastic Model},
    Type = {techreport}}
@article{article,
    Author = {Article, Art},
    Date = {2000-10-23},
    Journal = {A Journal},
    Number = {2},
    Title = {A Journal Article},
    Volume = {7},
    Pages = {123-234}}
@book{book,
    Author = {Book, Bob},
    Date = {2000},
    Publisher = {The Publisher},
    Location = {The Location},
    Edition = {2},
    Title = {A Book},
    Volumes = {3}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{test1.bib}
\begin{document}

\textcite{report} – with mk4ht oolatex: no space between title and number; month and day missing

\textcite{online} – with mk4ht oolatex: underscores missing in URL; month and day missing; “Visited on” instead of “Accessed”

\textcite{article} – with mk4ht oolatex: “number” instead of “no.”; month and day missing

\textcite{book} – with mk4ht oolatex: “edition” instead of “ed.”; “volumes” instead of “vols.”;

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is some problem with biblatex-chicago, with default authoryear, everything is ok. With current version of biblatex, I cannot compile your document even with pdflatex.

Comment: @user22851 You should consider contacting the `biblatex-chicago` author about this issue. AFAIK he does not frequent TeX.SE.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a probably bug in a package which requires the package maintainer's attention.